# Registering using Facebook API. Fields do not show up in iFrame

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, registration, facebook-login

- if I am already sign in, I can see the register button. But if sign out of Facebook, the iframe is blank. There is nothing it.

The other problem that I have, if I add fields to the iframe, again nothing is shown in iframe (even when I am logged in. Where could be the problem. Here is my code

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
             client_id=683316051721681& 
             redirect_uri=http://www.mytimesheet.us/fb_redirect.php
        ">
</iframe>
```

With fields name below, the register does not work at all

```
fields= [
{'name':'name'},
{'email:'email'}
]
```

Note: I have used [this nice tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/user-signup-using-facebook-data.html) but it is not working for me.

Comment: I would suggest not using the registration dialog because it been removed in API v2.0. So even if you get it to work it will stop working at 4/30/2015

Comment: this is the iFrame method. I am not sure if this presents a dialog. It does only to submit the data.

Comment: I meant the registration plugin. Look at the top of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/v2.0

Comment: Thanks for the link. what other methods should I use?

Comment: Use login and ask the user for permission for the data you need